# How to let JPA find generated entities (with spring-data)?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a Maven plugin that is supposed to generated JPA entities from a DSL. The entities are generated directly as ByteCode, i.e. without an intermediate java source (using ByteBuddy). The generation works fine. But the problem is that my entity isn't found by the hibernate orm. The error occurs in: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242), and the exception is a ClassNotFoundException. Does the hibernate instrumentation require the java code of the entity? Or how can I let hibernate know about my entity?
Further background: I use spring-data-jpa, and configured the EntityScan with the correct basePackage. My maven plugin is run in the compile phase (immediately after the compilation of the source code).

Comment: Can you check that the generated .class files are in the target directory with the correct package?

Comment: Yes, the classes are generated into the target dir. Meanwhile I saw that the class was not within the correct package. The package and the source folder hierarchy did not match. Now everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works as designed. The only problem is to take care that the package of the class and the folder hierarchy match, and that these packages are added as basePackages for the EntityScan.